# Issues with G+ Button in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

http://noblue.co.uk/blog/cloud-help-company-adapt-changing-working-environment/

The post is alwaying sharing wrong image to google plus. You can see the error in http://screencast.com/t/TBsgSGfopM

How we rectify this? I am using following code:

```
<div class="google_share">
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="tall"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an problem by google, it's a problem by your side.
Google search for a image and found it: The popup background (http://noblue.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/popup_case.png)

You must explicit add Meta informations in the **header** (Open-Graph) of your Site with following informations:

```
 <meta property="og:image" content="..." />
```

Look at your source, you adding already a meta, **duplicate it** and change the duplicat extra for google:

```
 <meta itemprop="image" content="http://noblue.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Advantages-of-cloud-computing-100x80.jpg">
```

**EDIT:**

Forgot 'em! You must add for Open Graph a additional Reference to your HTML-Tag:

```
 <html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

Comment: Hi, Yes i added them but its always show same image: <meta property="og:image" content="http://noblue.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Advantages-of-cloud-computing-100x80.jpg"/>